# Flask Teardown Appcontext Too Many Arguments

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting a strange error when trying to run my Flask app. I set the teardown_appcontext to be a function I have to close the database: `app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)`. When I visit the site or initialize the database, I get the error: `TypeError: close_db() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

In testing, I set the arguments for close_db to *arg and it worked without issues, but when I print *arg it returns `None`. Why is it angry about getting too many arguments if nothing is being passed to close_db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you decorated your `close_db` function with `app.teardown_appcontext()`, the `close_db` function will be appended to `teardown_appcontext_funcs` list.

Then when the application context tears down `Flask` will call `do_teardown_appcontext()` for you.

As we can see Flask source code: `app.py`

```
def do_teardown_appcontext(self, exc=_sentinel):
    if exc is _sentinel:
        exc = sys.exc_info()[1]
    for func in reversed(self.teardown_appcontext_funcs):
        func(exc)  <-- here
    appcontext_tearing_down.send(self, exc=exc)
```

In the place I marked an arrow above, it passed the argument `exc`. That means to avoid the `TypeError` exception, your `close_db` need an corresponding argument.

Comment: Ahhh great find! I respect that you looked through the source code to find this. Thanks so much!

Comment: @wowo878787 I faced the same issue and came across your answer. Simply adding `*args` to arguments of a teardown method helped. But I still don't understand why (Maybe I'm too new to Flask). Could you, please, clarify what is the argument it tries to pass to the teardown? Why it appears? Even its tutorial says nothing about this argument.